# Xcode6(Swift)にて、60進法を利用したカウントダウンの作成の手順

Tags: swift, xcode

60進法を利用したカウントダウンを作りたいのですが、以下のコードだと
「2分」ではなく、「120秒」として表示されてしまいます。

```js
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //最初に表示されるスタート地点の数字
    var timerCount = 120
    var timer = NSTimer()

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    func Counting(){
        timerCount -= 1
        myLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

ビルドしたらすぐにカウントダウンが始まるという設定なのですが、
60進法を利用した書き方が分かりません。

お詳しい方がいましたら、ご回答どうか宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

書式などは考慮していませんが、こういう事でしょうか？

```
myLabel.text = "\(timerCount / 60) min \(timerCount % 60) sec"
```

変数だけではなく、式も指定できます。
ただし timerCountが整数でない場合はもう少し考慮が必要になります。

Comment: flied onion様、ご丁寧な回答有り難うございます！お陰で無事、解決する事ができました！分かりやすい回答、本当に有り難うございます！

Answer (score 1):

整数除算と剰余でよいのでは。

```
let m = timerCount / 60
let s = timerCount % 60
myLabel.text = "\(m)分\(s)秒"
```

Comment: pgrho様、ご丁寧な回答有り難うございます！お陰で無事、解決する事ができました！分かりやすい回答、本当に有り難うございます！